# FreeBSD command-line tool to convert text file to image

Tags: image-processing

Example **text** file:

```
$ cat test.txt
 _   _      _ _
| | | | ___| | | ___
| |_| |/ _ \ | |/ _ \
|  _  |  __/ | | (_) |
|_| |_|\___|_|_|\___/
```

Example output (generated with `convert` from **ImageMagick**):

[image: Text to image using ImageMagick]

Are there any command-line **alternatives** to ImageMagick that works on **FreeBSD**?

**Further notes**:

- I know there is a FreeBSD version of ImageMagick. I am asking for alternatives to ImageMagick that work on FreeBSD.